How should I deal with a heat pump line hole that was filled with cement?
Someone partially filled the heat pump line hole with cement on the inside of my house. I’m pretty sure you’re supposed to use putty or silicone or something else - but not cement. It’s on the heat pump lines insulation and wires.
How do I fix this?

Does the heat pump work properly? If it does then this may not be an issue at all until it is time to replace it.

while odd, it would be perfectly fine

Depending on the thickness of the "cement" it may be fine.  3" thick is fine.  1" thick will probably eventually need a reapplication (or replacement with other material).

All should be fine if the cement touches only a layer of flexible insulation around the lines, and not the lines themselves, i.e.,

Allowing the lines to expand and contract with temperature changes
Not causing the lines to impact the cement and vibrate against it when the heat pump is operating.

As for removing cement, should it be necessary, a chisel and hammer could quickly do the job, but use care! A punctured line can cause injury and destroy the heat pump.

Probably wouldn't destroy the heat pump. But it would require patching/replacing the line and replacing all the refrigerant.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact, if the pump is running when a line is punctured, it might well destroy the compressor, too, running unlubed. That said, the lines are fairly heavy, so due care chiseling concrete should be OK.
